# Did I just lose my hard-worked Newly Created Topic?

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro, documentation, documentation-drafts

Edit: Can I now go and create the Topic with 3-4 examples and a Remarks section or it will be lost again?

Edit-after-Answer: Thank you SO again, as promised here is the [Partitions topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/apache-spark/5822/partitions#t=20160907223530590221), awaiting approval! :)

---

I created (my first time) a nice topic in [Apache-Spark Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/apache-spark), called **Partitions**. I am pretty sure I submitted it.

But then I wanted to add a new example (not edit the existing ones), so I clicked the plus sign for adding a new example. It created two examples (or I clicked it twice?), so when I tried to submit the new example, the by-accident-created previous example was empty, thus the submission would not be accepted.

As a result, I went ahead and navigated to the empty example and clicked on Discard. The page redirected somewhere else. Right now I have no idea if the new example was submitted, but even if it didn't I don't care, I can write it again.

However, the whole topic took me much time to create and I put a lot of effort on it. However, I cannot seem to view it. Is it lost? :///////

[image]

Edit:

After searching my browser's history, I couldn't find anything, but I have three 404s:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/apache-spark/drafts/72176
2. https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/apache-spark/drafts/72180
3. https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/apache-spark/drafts/72201

Here is my view:

[image]

Moreover, notice that I clicked on "Create New Topic", not "Request a Topic".

Comment: I see a couple of suggestions that you have made that are awaiting approval.

Comment: @JoeW correct, but these are on already created topics. Now, I created a whole new Topic, called **Partitions**, and I cannot see it anywhere! Hmmm, I am going to brute-forcily search my browser history

Comment: No @ivarni, see my edit.. Oh my God, it seems like it got lost...!? :///////// I feel sad..Pretty much like when the old female turtle died in Sammy the Turtle...

Comment: I reviewed the few items that I could find and had pending reviews, in case that is related to the issue you have. Might need others the review as well....

Comment: @rene thanks, but I didn't got any notification. The 2 drafts I have now, have `STATUS:  Awaiting approval`, but these are not the ones I am referring to.

Comment: Yeah, I hoped the topic was among those waiting for review :(

Comment: You do have [10 pending drafts](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2411320/gsamaras?tab=documentation&sort=topicdrafts). I recall that is the maxium. That would mean the system should have barked at you, not eat your topic ...

Comment: @rene most of them are dead, I mean I was told to post them in another topic, let me retract them.

Comment: @gsamaras The draft limit is Docs-wide, so having 2 in apache-spark and 8 elsewhere would cause you to hit the limit.

Comment: @TylerH but some of them are rejected, I thought they would have being gone by now. How can I kill them? And hopefully, when ones leaves, the new topic I created will be displayed! :D

Comment: Then we are only left why you didn't get an error and worse of all the system let you believe you were OK to create a new topic.

Comment: @gsamaras If they are rejected then they should be gone... that'd be another error. You can delete them per tag; go to the tag for the draft, and on the dashboard view, your drafts for that tag should be listed at the top-right.

Comment: I managed to delete one, I **couldn't** delete the rejected ones, they are not appearing under "My Drafts". Bad news are that the topic that I created with much effort doesn't get displayed there, thus it must be a gonner...So @rene, you may want to post an answer on that... :/

Comment: Thanks for the offer but it is a little thin what I bring to the table here. I rather have a dev look into why you didn't get an proper error.

Comment: @TylerH I have some rejected drafts in [tag:c] that cannot be deleted by what you suggested (and that's weird)! Now, I was able to delete only one draft. In the topic that I did create, I had 3-5 examples and remarks, so now way I can write it all over again and get it to be submitted..

Comment: Did you click the "Discard" button, which is in the bottom-right corner of the page? Did it show you [this warning](http://i.stack.imgur.com/inM7P.png)?

Comment: @Roman I clicked the bottom-right button Discard on that example that was empty, making it possible for the new example to get submitted. I think I got a warning, but it should be referring to that example (but probably wouldn't). I don't remember if this the warning.

Comment: To delete an example you would have to click a small trash bin icon to the right of that example's title in the main (preview) section of the page. The "Discard" button you clicked is for removing the entire draft. It has a tooltip "discard **entire** edit draft" and a warning "Are you sure you want to discard all changes, **deleting** this draft?" (emphasis mine). So bad news: you deleted the draft yourself and I doubt it can be undeleted.

Comment: I did try the tiny trash too. Well, I clicked discard for the empty example, and to be honest I feared this might happen, *but*, I had no other choice, it wouldn't leave me submit the new example..@Roman.

Comment: How many pokemen pictures were there in your new topic?

Comment: If you mean Pokemon, 0 @Hack-R, that might be the reason the system discarded by new topic..It's like the JavaScript answers that are not favored, because... "not enough jQuery in it!"... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm trying to reproduce this error and I haven't been able to. It *might* have been fixed. When I load up on topic drafts and try to create a new topic, I get the following error:

> You have the maximum of 10 outstanding topic drafts. Please submit your drafts for review and wait for other users to review them.

Until I can figure out how to reproduce the error, I'm going to mark this as [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro). But please let me know if there is a procedure to reproduce it.

Looking in the database, I can still find the text of your deleted draft. I pasted it [this revision](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/d66ea60d-265e-43ab-b524-05cecb796d0a/view-source) for your convenience.

Comment: O lala, that's me, I can see me in that text! Bravisimo Jon! Now, when someone accepts the creation of the Partitions topic, I will go ahead and populate it with that! :)

Comment: Thank you very much Jon again, as promised here is the [Partitions topic](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/apache-spark/5822/partitions#t=20160907223530590221), awaiting approval! :)