# Bounty and documentation

Tags: discussion, support, documentation, reputation, bounty

I am trying to understand how the Documentation awards points when you link to it. I posted an answer in this [Apache Bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38964007/active-tasks-is-a-negative-number-spark-ui), got upvoted, and then the super SO team helped [me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332668/did-i-just-lose-my-hard-worked-newly-created-topic).

So I thought I could update my answer with one Documentation link, and so I did. Later, my answer got awarded a bounty and 1 upvote.

I got +65, which means that the bounty and the documentation has no effect?

I mean ***I*** would expect to get nothing from an upvote to an answer that links to the documentation, but get something nice for a bounty in an answer that links to the documentation.

---

Note: This is not a complaint, I just want to understand what is happening..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at [your reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2411320/gsamaras?tab=reputation), I see the +5 for topic citation:

[image: Citation reputation gain.]

Citation reputation is triggered by the [first upvote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334095/1438). Bounty awards don't count. (Neither, in case it comes up, do accept votes trigger the citation +5.) Nor do they increase the reputation earned for citing Docs. In essence, an upvote (and only an upvote) validates the usefulness of the citation. We'd like to encourage these links because there's a [potential symbiotic relationship](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334100/1438). Bounties are orthogonal to those goals.

Comment: "Bounties are orthogonal to those goals." this was what I was looking for Jon, thanks! :)